Running application as application user
I notice that most of the React/Next.js/Yarn examples have you install everything to run as root, but that most people recommend running the app as an application user so that the application does not own its own code (this makes sense to me).
When installing as root with Dockerfile and using pnp, yarn install installs all the dependencies in root's home directory and hard codes the paths in .pnp.cjs and .pnp.loader.mjs.
package.json has (among other things):
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },

Running the server as root with e.g.:
CMD ["yarn", "dev"]

runs the server as expected.
However if we do:
USER app_user
CMD ["yarn","dev"]

it reads the path to Next from .pnp.loader.mjs and fails of permission errors because it's trying to access and update root's Yarn environment:
Error: Required package exists but could not be accessed (eACCES: permission denied, access '/root/.yarn/berry/cache/next-npm-14.2.5-ce63d89d89-10c0.zip/node_modules/next/').
# ...
Missing package: next@virtual:10d0ddd8962b160e8b7988b5b1cf9ce26b9a58b41ec7af94ce9595f61af7631df76c6dd2f22bd9f3088af482b8c60bcf3382616263c556f0e3ba392e203ea268#npm:14.2.5
Expected package location: /usr/local/app/.yarn/__virtual__/next-virtual-86a0c6e4d9/4/root/.yarn/berry/cache/next-npm-14.2.5-ce63d89d89-10c0.zip/node_modules/next/

Here is the listing showing the .yarn directory in /usr/local/app:
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Aug  5 19:29 .yarn

It makes sense we got that error, since we don't want to update or access the unzipped modules root owns if our purpose is to not have the app own its code.
So apparently the app_user needs access to this directory.  I suppose I could start changing permissions, but since this would give the app_user permissions to update the code it's actually running, I may as well just install everything as the app_user to be sure I've gotten everything needed.
So I update my Dockerfile like so:
# ...
# Have to switch to this user or path to root owned cache is used by
# yarn pnp creating permission errs
ENV SERVICE_NAME=app_user
USER $SERVICE_NAME

RUN mkdir -p ~/bin
RUN corepack enable --install-directory ~/bin

COPY demo/.yarnrc.yml ./
... rest omitted

Here I'm doing the whole install as the user $SERVICE_NAME and not just switching to that user after install before running the app.
This means the code is owned by that app user, which would mean that user could update the code if it were hacked somehow. It's better than running as root since only the app's code could be altered, but it seems less than ideal to me.
What is the correct way of running the app as a non-root user?

Since a Docker image has an immutable copy of the application source code, it might not make sense to try to run a dev server.  Does it work better to RUN yarn build (before you switch to the non-root user), and then set CMD ["yarn", "start"]?  If you're just trying to learn front-end programming, you may find it easier to use Node directly on its host so you're not also trying to debug Docker at the same time.

Checkout https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile for the official Dockerfile

package.json has
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint"
},
I get the same error due to not having permissions to unzip the modules into .yarn/virtual/** whether or not I do yarn run build first
